# Error when removing item in listView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I got error at this line:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Logcat gives this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Anyone can help me?

```
//method to remove list item
private void removeItemFromList(int position) {

    final int deletePosition = position;

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");

    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

            // main code on after clicking yes
            arr.remove(deletePosition);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

Comment: Show full crash logs

Comment: logcat shows java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ina.medicalclock.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:122)   @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: What is line number 122 in `MainActivity.java` ??

Comment: arr.remove(deletePosition);

Comment: Means `arr` is `null` and you are also doing it in wrong way

Comment: So, **arr** must set the value right?

Answer (score 0):

Call  `removeAt(deletePosition)` onClick of Yes

```
public void removeAt(int deletePosition) {
            arr.remove(deletePosition);
            notifyItemRemoved(deletePosition);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(deletePosition, arr.size());
        }
```